# Principal part of Laurent Series for $\frac{1}{(1-\cosh(z))^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series, hyperbolic-functions

in this exercise I am asked to provide the principal part of the Laurent series of
$$\frac{1}{(1-\cosh(z))^2}$$
And i am kinda struggling with fonding a solution or even a pattern towards one

Thanks in advance to everyone keen to help

Comment: Note that the only poles are at $z\in 2\pi i\mathbb{Z}$ and by periodicity of $\cosh$ you only need to consider the pole $z=0$.  Can you finish off from here?

Comment: So the only pole is $z=0$ with order 2 then I can try and evaluate the residue. This is how i would tackle the problem

Comment: There are no residue since the function is even, but there are the $1/z^2$ and $1/z^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it quite differently than @Nosrati, taking a very down-to-earth and unimaginative route.

First, $\cosh x=1+x^2/2! + x^4/4! +\cdots$, so that $1-\cosh x=-x^2[1/2!+x^2/4!+\cdots]$. You want to square this and take the reciprocal:
\begin{align}
\left[x^2\left(\frac12+\frac{x^2}{24}+\frac{x^4}{720}+\cdots\right)\right]^{-2}
&=x^{-4}\left[\frac14+\frac{x^2}{24}+\frac{x^4}{320}+\cdots\right]^{-1}\\
&=x^{-4}\left[4-\frac{2x^2}3+\frac{11x^4}{180}+\cdots\right]\\
&=4x^{-4}-\frac23x^{-2}+\frac{11}{180}+\cdots\,,
\end{align}
where the only thing that slows your hand computation down is doing the long division of $1/4+x^2/14+x^4/320+\cdots$ into $1$.

Comment: first of all I would like to thank you both for the explanation. I have to admit that route computation is more clear to me, and it overlaps with one of my trials in solving this excercise. I stopped while trying to evaluate the inverse, and even from your answer I get the result but I am not able to reconstruct the computation. Can you please go more in depth?

Comment: sry there is a typo (the route that you have taken during the computation) in the second sentence

Comment: “… not able to reconstruct …” — I assume you’re talking about the computation for division of power series. It’s just like the division of polynomials that you learned in high school, but you arrange the monomials in ascending order rather than descending. Impossible to describe the process step by step in the static medium of printed mathematics.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1-\cosh z)^2=3-4\cosh z+\cosh2z$$
then
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{(1-\cosh z)^2}
&= \dfrac{1}{3-4\cosh z+\cosh2z} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{3-4 \left(1+\frac{1}{2!}z^2+\frac{1}{4!}z^4+\frac{1}{6!}z^6+\cdots\right) + \left(1+\frac{4}{2!}z^2+\frac{16}{4!}z^4+\frac{64}{6!}z^6+\cdots\right)} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{\frac{1}{4}z^4+\frac{1}{24}z^6+\frac{1}{320}z^8+\cdots} \\
&= \frac{4}{z^4}-\frac{2}{3z^2}+\dfrac{11}{180}+\sum_{n\geq1}a_{2n}z^{2n}\cdots
\end{align}
and you find the principal part.